# Neither Linux mint nor Ubuntu can be installed on Alienware m14x r2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, linux-mint

I have bought a laptop from Alienware a few years ago and recently have tried to switch to Linux. However, I have had so many issues with any version of Linux installing that I may be forced to use windows. If anyone has any clue what I should do PLEASE tell me as I have no clue what to do next.

Full story:
So about a year ago I started to install Linux mint. I don't remember much but I couldn't fully install Linux mint, becaue the installer crashed repeatedly and never let me access my partition list. It always showed nothing under partions but worked fine in the disks app.The best I could do was run a live cd. But I assumed that mint was what was causing the issue, so i decided to just use windows for the time. Now, I decided to instead use Ubuntu. I downloaded the latest version and ran a .exe which added Ubuntu to my list of OS's from windows boot loader. So I launched Ubuntu and didn't hit any keys when I was told that no root file system was defined, and to correct this In the partitioning menu. I then booted into demo mode and one year later, I had the exact same problem. I could not see a single drive on the install menu. If anyone thinks that additional info would be useful PLEASE tell me as I can probably post it

Also I meant to post it as beautron7 so all replies will be as beautron7

Comment: See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Give [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99038/why-the-ubuntu-installer-does-not-detect-the-hard-drive-during-installation) thread a shot. Specifically the answer from Krige. Linux can be a bit buggy at times with certain hardware. It's possible that the Linux distros may not be able to recognize your HDD. I've had the same problem trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop (a Lenovo). I never did get it figured out and resorted to running it in a virtual environment. It's a bit slower, but it does the job.